# How to find the local minimum, local maximum, global minimum and global maximum of a function within a given definition range?

Tags: functions

Functions and definition fields are as follows

```
2 Sin[x] - x - Log[x + 1], {x, 0, 3 \[Pi]}
```

How to find the local minimum, local maximum, global minimum and global maximum of a function within a given definition range?

It is better to draw an image and mark the position of these points in the image

```
ClearAll["`*"]
f[x_] = x E^x + 1/2;
Maximize[{f[x], -2 <= x <= 2}, x]
Minimize[{f[x], -2 <= x <= 2}, x]
sol1 = Solve[{D[f[x], x] == 0, D[f[x], {x, 2}] > 0, -2 <= x <= 2}, x]
sol2 = Solve[{D[f[x], x] == 0, D[f[x], {x, 2}] < 0, -2 <= x <= 2}, x]
Plot[f[x], {x, -2, 2}, 
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[10], Green, Point[{x, f[x]} /. sol2], 
   Red, Point[{x, f[x]} /. sol1]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Can the global maximum and global minimum points also be marked?

Update 1：

```
ClearAll["`*"]
f[x_] = x^3 - 2 x + 3;
xr = -10 <= x <= 20
D[f[x], x] // Factor
gmax = Maximize[{f[x], xr}, x]
gmin = Minimize[{f[x], xr}, x]
lmin = Solve[{D[f[x], x] == 0, D[f[x], {x, 2}] < 0, xr}, x]
lmax = Solve[{D[f[x], x] == 0, D[f[x], {x, 2}] > 0, xr}, x]
Plot[f[x], {x, xr[[1]], xr[[3]]}, 
 Epilog -> {{Darker@Green, AbsolutePointSize[20], 
    Point[{x, f[x]} /. gmax[[2]]], AbsolutePointSize[16], White, 
    Point[{x, f[x]} /. gmax[[2]]]}, {Darker@Red, 
    AbsolutePointSize[20], Point[{x, f[x]} /. gmin[[2]]], 
    AbsolutePointSize[16], White, Point[{x, f[x]} /. gmin[[2]]]}, 
   AbsolutePointSize[8], Green, Point[{x, f[x]} /. lmin], Red, 
   Point[{x, f[x]} /. lmax]}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 1.2, ImageSize -> 400]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
f[x_] = 2 Sin[x] - x - Log[x + 1];
gmax = Maximize[{f[x], 0 <= x <= 3 π}, x]
gmin = Minimize[{f[x], 0 <= x <= 3 π}, x]
lmin = Solve[{D[f[x], x] == 0, D[f[x], {x, 2}] < 0, 
   0 <= x <= 3 π}, x]
lmax = Solve[{D[f[x], x] == 0, D[f[x], {x, 2}] > 0, 
   0 <= x <= 3 π}, x]
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 3 π}, 
 Epilog -> {{Darker@Green, AbsolutePointSize[20], 
    Point[{x, f[x]} /. gmax[[2]]], AbsolutePointSize[16], White, 
    Point[{x, f[x]} /. gmax[[2]]]}, {Darker@Red, 
    AbsolutePointSize[20], Point[{x, f[x]} /. gmin[[2]]], 
    AbsolutePointSize[16], White, Point[{x, f[x]} /. gmin[[2]]]}, 
   AbsolutePointSize[8], Green, Point[{x, f[x]} /. lmin ], Red, 
   Point[{x, f[x]} /. lmax]}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 1.2]
```

[image]

Comment: Can the global maximum and global minimum points also be marked?